# Unexpected end of call when app is started using Web Trigger

Tags: sip-server, mobicents, restcomm

I've created an RVD app enabling Web Trigger. One of the modules of this app contains a collect step. When I start the app using Web Trigger, the call ends few seconds after say the prompt message of the collect step, while I'm still dialing some digits.

If I register a number to this app in restcomm-management and call to this number using the same SIP client I used in the situation above, its possible to dial all the digits in the collect step and the app continue executing normally.

The restcomm log since the HTTP call made to Web Trigger until the end of  the SIP call is shown bellow (SIP messages and timestamp INFO omitted by due to text limit). Any idea will be welcome.

Thank you!

```
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.http.resources.RvdController] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-8) using restcomm host: 127.0.0.1 and port: 8080
[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.catalina.session.ConvergedStandardSession] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) maxInactiveInterval = 1800
[org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) No cache or cacheManager properties have been set.  Authorization cache cannot be obtained.
[org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) No cache or cacheManager properties have been set.  Authorization cache cannot be obtained.
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "uninitialized
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.InitializeOutbound sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "queued
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.GetCallInfo sender : class akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: uninitialized
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.StartInterpreter
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: acquiring asr info
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.asr.AsrResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: acquiring tts info
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.tts.api.SpeechSynthesizerResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "queued
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.patterns.Observe sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "queued
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.GetCallInfo sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: acquiring call info
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.patterns.Observing
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: acquiring call info
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.CallResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "queued
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Dial sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "acquiring media gateway info
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.MediaGatewayResponse sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "acquiring media session
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.MediaGatewayResponse sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "acquiring bridge
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.MediaGatewayResponse sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "acquiring remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.MediaGatewayResponse sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Current State: uninitialized
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.patterns.Observe
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Current State: uninitialized
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.InitializeConnection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "initializing remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.patterns.Observing sender : class akka.actor.LocalActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Current State: initializing
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.EndpointCredentials
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "initializing remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.ConnectionStateChanged sender : class akka.actor.LocalActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Current State: closed
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.OpenConnection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310)  ********** Connection Current State: opening halfway
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310)  ********** Connection Processing Message: jain.protocol.ip.mgcp.message.CreateConnectionResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "opening remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.ConnectionStateChanged sender : class akka.actor.LocalActorRef

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.util.B2BUAHelper] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) SIP SESSION is NULL
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "dialing
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.Servlet3SipServletResponseImpl sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: initializing call
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.CallStateChanged

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.util.B2BUAHelper] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) SIP SESSION is NULL
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "ringing
[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.SipServletResponseImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) ackRequest just created ACK sip:bob@127.0.0.1:5060;transport=udp;registering_acc=127_0_0_1 SIP/2.0

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.Servlet3SipServletResponseImpl sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) Using the real ip address of the sip client sip:bob@127.0.0.1:5060 as a request uri of the ACK

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310) Just sent out ACK : ACK sip:bob@127.0.0.1:5060 SIP/2.0

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310)  ********** Connection Current State: half open
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6310)  ********** Connection Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.UpdateConnection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Current State: modifying
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** Connection Processing Message: jain.protocol.ip.mgcp.message.ModifyConnectionResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "updating remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.ConnectionStateChanged sender : class akka.actor.LocalActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: initializing call
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.CallStateChanged
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) Voiceinterpreter: akka://RestComm/user/$rc sent CreateMediaGroup to Call: akka://RestComm/user/$qc
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "in progress
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.CreateMediaGroup sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6309) group is null or terminated, will get new one for call: akka://RestComm/user/$qc
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) 1 MediaGroup for call: akka://RestComm/user/$qc will be sent to sender: akka://RestComm/user/$rc
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: acquiring call media group
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.CallResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) VoiceInterpreter: akka://RestComm/user/$rc sent StartMediaGroup for callMediaGroup: akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a CallMediaGroup isTerminated: false
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: initializing call media group
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroup] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) MediaGroup: akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a got StartMediaGroup from: akka://RestComm/user/$rc endpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd isTerminated: false
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.patterns.Observing
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroup] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) MediaGroup :akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a state: uninitialized session: 65 will ask to get IvrEndpoint
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroup] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) MediaGroup :akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a state: acquiring ivr session: 65 ivr endpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Md will ask to get Link
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroup] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) MediaGroup :akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a state: acquiring link session: 65 link: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Nd endpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd initializeLink sent, endpoint isTerminated: false
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Link] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Link: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Nd ,received InitializeLink message from sender: akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Link] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Link: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Nd ,state: uninitialized ,primaryEndpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd ,secondaryEndpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Md
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Link] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Link: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Nd ,state: uninitialized InviteEndpoint sent to primaryEndpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Link] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Link: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Nd ,state: initializing primary ,primaryEndpointId: mobicents/bridge/17@127.0.0.1:2427 ,secondaryEndpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Md secondaryEndpoint isTerminated: false
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroup] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) MediaGroup :akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a state: initializing link session: 65 link: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Nd will ask to open Link
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6314)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: initializing call media group
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroupStateChanged
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.http.resources.RvdController] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Received Restcomm POST request
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6305)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: downloading rcml
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6305)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.http.client.DownloaderResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: ready
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.rcml.Tag
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: pausing
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: akka.actor.ReceiveTimeout$
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: ready
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.rcml.Tag
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: processing gather children
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.cache.DiskCacheResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: processing gather children
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.StartGathering

[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-497) Request event dispatched to RestComm

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: gathering
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroupResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) Digits collected: 
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) Attribute, Action or Digits is null, FinishGathering failed, moving to the next available verb
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: finish gathering
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.rcml.End
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "in progress
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Hangup sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef    

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** Connection Current State: open
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** Connection Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.CloseConnection

[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.util.B2BUAHelper] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) SIP SESSION is NULL
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "closing remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.sip.message.Servlet3SipServletResponseImpl sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** Connection Current State: closing
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.Connection] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313)  ********** Connection Processing Message: jain.protocol.ip.mgcp.message.DeleteConnectionResponse
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "closing remote connection
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.ConnectionStateChanged sender : class akka.actor.LocalActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Completing Call
[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) Invalidating the sip session (49108927_0fe40796_57a5b08a_879c3206;dd1cd16f62ac436766562edd7ab80ab4@127.0.0.1;879c3206;RestComm)
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Call: akka://RestComm/user/$qc about to stop bridge endpoint: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.MediaGroup] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) MediaGroup :akka://RestComm/user/$qc/$a at postStop, about to stop ivr endpoint :akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Md
[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) Invalidating the following sip application session 879c3206;RestComm
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.MediaGateway] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Gateway: akka://RestComm/user/$a about to stop endpoint path: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd isTerminated: false sender: akka://RestComm/user/$qc
[org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) The following sip application session 879c3206;RestComm has been invalidated
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.BridgeEndpoint] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Bridge: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Kd bridge id: mobicents/bridge/17@127.0.0.1:2427 at postStop, sender: akka://RestComm/deadLetters
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.mgcp.MediaGateway] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6313) Gateway: akka://RestComm/user/$a about to stop endpoint path: akka://RestComm/user/$a/$Md isTerminated: true sender: akka://RestComm/deadLetters
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Current State: hanging up
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308)  ********** VoiceInterpreter's akka://RestComm/user/$rc Processing Message: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.CallStateChanged
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) ********** Call's akka://RestComm/user/$qc Current State: "completed
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6308) ********** Call akka://RestComm/user/$qc Processing Message: "org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.telephony.DestroyMediaGroup sender : class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6319) VoiceIntepreter: akka://RestComm/user/$rcAt the postStop() method. Will clean up Voice Interpreter. Keep calls: false
[org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6319) At postStop(), will clean up call
```

Message shown dialing 1, when using Web Trigger (MMS Log)

```
[RtpHandler] Dropping packet because payload type (126) is unknown.
```

Message shown dialing 1, when app is called using SIP Client (MMS Log)

```
[EventBuffer] Receive 1 tone
[PlayCollect] (mobicents/ivr/54) Tone '1' has been detected
[PlayCollect] (mobicents/ivr/54) Tone '1' has been detected: collected
[DetectorImpl] (mobicents/ivr/54) (detector) Delivered '1' tone
```

Message shown when the call ends unexpectedly, when using Web Trigger (MMS Log)

```
[RtpMember] rtt=2054713442 - 2054584926 - 127729 = 787 => 12ms
[PlayCollect] (mobicents/ivr/35) Timeout expired waiting for dtmf
[MGCP] tx=62 Started, message= NTFY mobicents/ivr/35@127.0.0.1:2427, call agent = localhost/127.0.0.1:2727
[MGCP] tx=62 was executed normaly
[MGCP] tx=147484061 Started, message= DLCX mobicents/bridge/25@127.0.0.1:2427, call agent = localhost/127.0.0.1:2727
[MGCP] tx=147484061 was executed normaly
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Restcomm do you use? 
Can you also check the MMS log when the application fails?

The MMS logs can be found at $RESTCOMM_HOME/mediaserver/log/server.log

Comment: Hi George, I've edited the post including the MMS logs. The version i'm using is 7.3.0-SNAPSHOT (built from rvd_master).

Comment: Hi George, did you found something that could help me? I really would like to participate TADHack tomorrow! My project depends on this.

Comment: Hi Guilherme! Does your built contain customizations? If not why not use the official binary from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestComm/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ ? Also, can you export and post your project as well as the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Orestis! When using the official binary I got a HTTP 404 trying to access http://localhost:8080/restcomm-management. JBoss started with this error message: "JBWEB000250: Child container with name  already exists." I no understand what I've done wrong. Rolled back the version, I recorded a video demonstrating the issue. I'm sharing it together with my app and instructions. (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mhq9mswszvq8zet/AAADW2cdvcRc_gqXPtSPbrWja?dl=0)

Comment: Guilherme, restcomm management tool has moved to root '/' context since https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues/281. Try accessing it at  http://localhost:8080/

Comment: More information about the WebTrigger can be found at http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-web-trigger-use-cases/